# Apache Cassandra-Querying Map User Defined Type

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-types

I have a table With map collections and type is a user defined type

```
create table servicetable
{
id UUID,
service map<text, frozen<typbs_servicevalues>>
primary key(id)
} WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id);

create type typbs_servicevalues
(
phone no text,
name text
);
```

If i have an input for phone number, and i write a query like this

select * from servicetable where service contains {phone no:'00098786'};

I get no data, even though i have that phone numebr in database. Where am i doing wrong. can anyone help out in this.

Comment: I would recommend you read http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html#reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__filtering-data-using-where

Comment: I have tried this before !!!! With that only I wrote the query !!! I got the above exception !!!!